# PHP Load.sql file with PHP variables

Tags: php, sql, file-get-contents

I have a long .sql query with variable ($email) and I saved it in a.sql file.
In my PHP file, I get $email from user input, and then I want to load this a.sql using

```
$query = file_get_contents("queryRadius.sql");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

, and then mysqli_query().
This method fail because $email in a.sql is not compiled.

I'm not sure whether there are some fancy methods to do this automatically, such as to ask PHP to compile $query again.
If no other method available, I will have to str_replace in the PHP. This will do the job but I think this is too specific for my current question, not general for all .sql loadings with variables. I want a general solution.

```
$query=str_replace(
    '$email',
    $email,
    $query
)；
```

Any ideas how to handle this?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand _too specific_, and _I want a general solution_. If you want some value in sql replaced with `$email` then use `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` is correct. What else do you want?

Comment: Does PHP contain some 're-compiling a string' method? Because if I wrote the sql in the php as a string, it will replace $email to my specific email got from user.

Comment: try to echo out what you get with `str_replace()` and please update your code in question that how you write `str_replace()` because currently you did not store its value into any variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Using str_replace() will do the job.

Comment: You could use a user-defined variable in your SQL instead. In your stored query, you use the variable in the relevant places - and then you fire off a tiny query first, that _sets_ this variable, before you execute the actual statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful